# Read last n line from url stream problem

Tags: java

I have problem to read last n lines from url. How to do that ? I have url.openstream but there is no contrsuctor for RandomAccessFile which has input for stream. Can somebody help me ? Is there meybe already library for this. ( I know how to implement with RandomAccess when I have file but how to change stream to file ).

Answer (score 2):

1. Open the URL stream as per usual.
2. Wrap the returned InputStream in a [`BufferedReader`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) so you can read it line by line.
3. Maintain a [`LinkedList`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) into which you will save the lines.
4. After reading each line from the BufferedReader:

   1. Add the line to the list.
   2. If the size of the list is greater than "`n`" then call [`LinkedList#removeFirst()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#removeFirst%28%29).
5. Once you have read all lines from the stream the list will contain the last "`n`" lines.

For example (untested, just for demonstration):

```java
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(url.openStream());
LinkedList<String> lines = new LinkedList<String>();
String line = null;
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
  lines.add(line);
  if (lines.size() > nLines) {
    lines.removeFirst();
  }
}
// Now "lines" has the last "n" lines of the stream.
```

Comment: Problem is that I read this in android and that is log file which can be size 100 MB ++ . I thought not to read all file.

Comment: @Damir, if all you have is an URL stream, then the only way the server will send you the end of the file is if you've consumed all of the previous content. Perhaps you should look into doing some byterange requests instead of requesting the entire log (but this will be rather complex in comparison to simply reading everything).

Comment: Implement servlet that brings you last N lines of file. Call serlvlet from you Android app.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry.  You're going to have to do this one yourself.  But don't worry because it's pretty simple.

You just need to keep track of the last `n` lines you have encountered since you started reading from the `UrlStream`.  Might I suggest using a [`Queue`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html)?

Basically you could do something like

```
public String[] readLastNLines(final URL url, final int n) throws IOException{
    final Queue<String> q = new LinkedList<String>();
    final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
    String line=null;
    while ((line = br.readLine())!=null)
    {
        q.add(line);
        if (q.size()>n) q.remove();
    }
    return q.toArray(new String[q.size()]);
}
```

`readLastNLines` returns an array containing the last `n` lines read from `url`.

Unfortunately, you cannot use a `RandomAccessFile` with a stream from the Internet because streams are, by definition, not random access.